# Input code in TinyMCE

Tags: symfony1, formatting, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE on my blog and it seems to be removing the code I'm trying to paste.

I want to add this:

```
<Files somefile.png>
    DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

(it's a .htaccess directive)

This gets saved ok (as &lt; and &gt; in the html), but when I **reopen** my form for editing, it gets transformed as :

```
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
```

Edit : I'm using TinyMCE in a *Symfony* form, using sfFormExtraPlugin.

Edit 2 : I tried verify_html: false .... 
now my code gets transformed as :

```
<p><files exec="" jpg=""><br /> DefaultType application/x-httpd-php<br /></files></p>
```

Edit 3: My tinyMCE config is :

```
  tinyMCE.init({
    mode:                              "exact",
    elements:                          "content_contents",
    theme:                             "advanced",
    width:                             "500px",
    height:                            "400px",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location:   "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align:      "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing:           true
    ,

    language : "fr",
        convert_urls : false,
        verify_html : false

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I responded to this on the [TinyMCE MoxieCode forums topic](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=88827#p88827) that was also opened by @Manu however I wanted to update this topic with my thoughts as well.

If I understand @Manu correctly, the problem is that the HTML source, while saving with **&lt** and **&gt** correctly is being interpreted as **<** and **>** when reloaded into TinyMCE.

If this is the case, then I believe the problem is that the *Symphony* plugin isn't encoding the HTML content prior to populating the TextArea that TinyMCE replaces. In other words, it leaves **&lt** when it should be loading **&lt;** so tinyMCE receives **&lt**

Comment: I'm able to see what I wish to see in tinymce by adding a htmlentities() before saving

Comment: but it gets saved with extras entities :)

Comment: I think I got it : htmlentities before the value is displayed, html_entities_decode before it gets saved :)

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing to the input when putting it back in to TinyMCE? If you're converting it to HTML or anything TinyMCE will clean it up as it's invalid HTML.

As a work around/experiment you could add File in the [custom_elements](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acustom_elements) option in your init.

**Update** As you  are accepting all sorts of code, you will probably have to turn off clean up altogether. Put `cleanup: false` in the config. If I were you I would implement your own custom formatting (like Stack/overflow does) and generate bold, underline, links etc formatting because it will give you a lot more control over the HTML generation, ie you could just print out everything exactly how it is (with escaping), and then turn the pre-defined symbols to `<strong>` tags, or what ever. This is be far the easiest way of generating safe, accurate HTML output, and in your case, probably the only way.

You would not want to use TinyMCE is this case...

Comment: adding File in custom_elements is not a viable solution, as I have a technical blog and have to paste blocs of code often.

Comment: Updated answer, should sort it for you.

Comment: Humm.. not the answer I was looking for, to be honest :)
You don't think there's a symfony or tinymce bug somewhere ? The code gets saved with &lt; and &gt; but when I edit it it gets re-interpreted as < > and cleaned up ?

Comment: Not a bug, they are jsut clashing with each other- or it might be TinyMCE alone. TinyMCE/Symphony is escaping the HTML in, and then when you edit/save it, TinyMCE sees it as invalid and deletes it. TinyMCE is your problem here, with input HTML and 'code' HTML, you have no way of telling which is which, therefore you need to cut one out. Maybe use BBCode...?

Comment: Oh, no. changing the value of escaping_strategy in settings.yml didn't help :'(

Comment: "input HTML and 'code' HTML, you have no way of telling which is which"... one is <html> the other is &lt;html&gt; -- or one is &lt;html&gt; and the other is &amp;lt;html&amp;gt;

Comment: Not when they are first input tho are they? `<b><Filename: blah.jpg></b> <span class="bold"><strong></strong></b>` Tell me which is which.. there's no way to tell, which is why you can't use HTML for formatting. StackOverflow doesn't use HTML for formatting  so if that doesn't tell you that you can't either I don't know what will.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the invalid HTML gets removed (the tinymce cleanup functionality).

A workaround could be to initialize tinymce using the [cleanup paramter](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acleanup):

```
cleanup: false,
```

I suggest you have a closer look at the tinymce initialization parameters

- [custom_elements](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acustom_elements)
- [valid_elements](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements)

and

- [cleanup](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acleanup)

Comment: Re-read the question and you'll see that the mark up is getting removed is &lt; and &gt; (once it's been re-loaded), which should not be parsed by TinyMCE...

Comment: entity-encoding seems to be on

Answer (score 0):

replace your < and >

```
< becomes: &lt;
> becomes: &gt;
```

Comment: TinyMCE replaces them, saves them as &lt and &gt

Answer (score 0):

Try including
`extended_valid_elements : "Files[]",`
In your config. It's used to unlock certain html tags like iframe. In the brackets you usually put the allowed options for the tag (like `[src|alt|id]`) so I'm not sure what to put there for your example ...

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer to your problem, tested by me and 100% working is to wrap your variable into `htmlspecialchars` in php like this example:

```
htmlspecialchars($myText)
```